# Plot shape once two conditions are met but don't repaint until it is met after 100 bars

Tags: pine-script

I want to plot a shape once two separate conditions are met and not replot again until the condition is met again 100 bars later. So far i've been playing around with the following;

```
    var bool bull1=na, bool bull2=na, var a_thisBar=1, var a_barCount=bar_index-a_thisBar, var b_thisBar=1, var b_barCount=bar_index-b_thisBar

    a4K:=sma(stoch(close,high,low,8),3)
    a5K:=sma(stoch(close,high,low,32),12)

    if a5K>50
         bull1:=true,a_thisBar:=bar_index
    if bull1 and a_barCount<25 and crossover(a4K,a4D)
         bull2:=true,bull1:=false

   plotshape(bull2,style=shape.arrowup,location=location.belowbar,color=color.blue,size=size.small)
```

Atm this is working fine but, understandably, it is plotting a shape every time the two conditions are met. What I would like it to do is plot it on the first instance and then not plot it again until the two conditions are met at least 100 bars after the first instance.

I have tried playing with variations of the following with no success;

```
    if a5K>50
        bull1:=true,a_thisBar:=bar_index
    if bull1 and a_barCount<25 and crossover(a4K,a4D) and b_barCount>100
        bull2:=true,bull1:=false,b_thisBar:=bar_index
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a variable which tells you if you can start counting (when your buy condition becomes `true`).

Have another variable to count number of bars after your buy condition becomes `true`.

Then wait for your buy condition to become `true` again, and check the value of your counter. When it is a valid buy signal, reset your counter.

Below is an example that uses a `crossunder(RSI, 50)` event to buy. The counter in my case is set to 15 for demonstration purposes. I plotted `X` marks when the crossunder takes place.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

var cnt = 0
var startCounting = false

_rsi = ta.rsi(close, 14)
_buy_condition = ta.crossunder(_rsi, 50)

startCounting := _buy_condition ? true : startCounting  // Start counting if the buy condition is true, keep the old value otherwise
cnt := startCounting ? cnt + 1 : cnt    // INcrement the counter if startCounting is true, keep the old value otherwise

canBuy = _buy_condition and cnt > 15
cnt := canBuy ? 0 : cnt     // If there is a buy signal, reset the counter for next buy signal

plotshape(_buy_condition, size=size.small)
plotshape(canBuy, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, text="Buy", size=size.small)
```

[image]